# Is it possible to use a fluent-bit record's timestamp?

Tags: fluent-bit

I'm trying to create a fluent-bit config which uses a record's timestamp to a custom key using a filter. Something like:

```
[INPUT]
  Name tail
  Path /some/path
  ... 

[FILTER]
  Name record_modifier
  Match *
  Record fluenbit_orig_ts SOME_MAGIC_WAY_TO_GET_UNIXTIME

[OUTPUT]
  Name           stdout
  Match          *
```

The rationale for this that I'm using several parsers, each has its own time format (`Time_Format`, as it's used in the regular expression parser. Even if I used `Time_Keep`, it won't help because the time is specified differently by different services, with a different `Time_Format`). I'd like the records getting to an `[OUTPUT}` to have the same key to describe the timestamp. In this example that key would be `fluenbit_orig_ts`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from the fluent-bit slack channel.

Seems like this is possible using [lua filters](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/lua). Specifically, this example seems to be relevant: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/scripts/append_tag.lua

Answer (score 1):

I've same issue.
According to @BugoK, I've solved.

This is lua script.

```
function append_tag(tag, timestamp, record)
    new_record = record
    new_record["log_time"] = os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return 1, timestamp, new_record
end
```

And this is td-agent-bit config.

```
[FILTER]                                                                                                 
Name lua                                                                                             
Match nginx.access                                                                                   
script override_time.lua                                                                             
call append_tag
```

And then restart td-agent-bit. It works~!